# How to get optimality gap using CPLEX C++ API?

Tags: c++, cplex, ilog

How can the optimality gap (relative and absolute) be obtained using CPLEX C++ API? Is there any function such as that would give the optimality gap?

[IBM: accessing the MIP relative optimality gap](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/accessing-mip-relative-optimality-gap-programmatically)

Found the above information but not able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Cplex.getMIPRelativeGap()
```

If Cplex is yout Cplex object